# How to use non-column variable in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am developing a trial Node.JS server which uses Sequelize ORM to interact with a postgres database.

I have a table of answers which some of them confirmed but some not("**confirmed**" is a column in "**answers**" table).

I want to send just confirmed answers if a regular user requests me and otherwise send all of answers; I recognize the regular users using a query parameter which I call it **isAdmin**(if isAdmin is 0 then it is a regular user).

So how can I use **isAdmin** parameter in where clause in Sequelize?

My best try is as below:

```
const isAdmin = req.params.isadmin
try{
    const result = await AnswersModel.Answer.findAll({
         where:
                sequelize.or(
                sequelize.and(
                    {confirmed: true},
                    isAdmin == false
                ),
                sequelize.and(
                    1==1,
                    isAdmin == true
                )
            )
}catch(error){
...
}
```

I didn't get any error but isAdmin condition is ineffective simply:(!

**Note**: I know I can do it using "row query" or a simple `if(){}else{}` style but I'm just trying to avoid it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to include all conditional filter building logic to `where` option. It has to be as simple as possible.

```
const where = {}
if (!isAdmin) {
  where.confirmed = true
}
const result = await AnswersModel.Answer.findAll({
 where
})
```

Comment: It seems this is the shortest way to do it, thanks.